# How to prevent parent row from getting deleted when deleting a child row in a many to many relationship (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two classes course and student, and three tables are created (student, course, student-course), what I am trying to do is to delete a course that is associated with the student in the (student-course) table  without deleting the student.

```
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = 
    {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Student> students;
}
```

k

```
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;


@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "stud_course", joinColumns ={ @JoinColumn(name = "student_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id")})
private Set<Course> courses;
```

Comment: If you dont want to delete a related object then don't have `CascadeType.REMOVE` enabled!

Comment: but I want to delete the relation between them, it throws a foreign key constraint failure

Comment: To stop the other end being deleted you remove that stupid cascade type. To resolve constraints you post HOW you are trying to delete the relation